# sum of floats gives no decimals in javascript

Tags: javascript, parsefloat

I have 2 strings that have a 0 and a 16,63 as follows:

```
var diferencia = "0";
var estalviPotencia = "16,63";
```

If I put an alert to see its value with two decimals I obtain:

```
alert(parseFloat(diferencia).toFixed(2)) -- returns 0,00
alert(parseFloat(estalviPotencia).toFixed(2)) -- returns 16,63
```

But if I actually sum them and then get the value I get:

```
alert((parseFloat(diferencia) + parseFloat(estalviPotencia)).toFixed(2)); -- returns 16,00
```

I can't see the error and why I am obtaining that number...

Edit por possible duplicate:

I am NOT saying that the decimals are wrong as said on that answer (which asks why there so MANY decimals but why I am NOT obtaining any decimals at all.

Comment: __NO__... https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/t679kd1m/

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, You read it wrong...

Comment: @RayonDabre I don't understand why it IS happening to me though (I'm working in asp.net) It clearly is supposed to work.

Comment: I'm not sure but you are definitely doing it wrong!

Comment: Yeah I misread it. reopened it.

Comment: OKAY I found the problem. It seems like putting a comma ',' on the 16,63 makes the parseFloat to actually ignore whatever is next to the comma!

Comment: Got it - if you can remove the duplicate thing i'll add the answer.
in here - it's because it's a comma instead of a decimal point, so it's only reading the numerical characters up to the non-numerical character

Damn - you beat me to it!

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, Need to close it as _"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a comma instead of a decimal point in

```
var estalviPotencia = "16,63";
```

so it's only reading the numerical characters up to the non-numerical character.

change it into a decimal point and it'll work correctly.

Comment: That's indeed the solution. Is there any way to work WITH the commas? because I'm seeing I'll have to put a lot of .replace(',', '.') everywhere....

Comment: Unfortunately str.replace is the way to go - probably best to write a function to handle the replace - parse - convertToFixed method, then you won't be having to rewrite it all each time